# How to convert date to dd-mm-yy in phtml?

Tags: php, date

Like `<?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date)); ?>` but in phtml?
how do I change it?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
well, thx

*edit 
I need to convert this value of input type text in phtml.

```
<input style="width:160%;" id="sp_to" type="text" class="kb-inpfield datepicker" name="sp_to" validate="isDate" value="{$specific_price_to|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" />
```

Comment: what is the problem???

Comment: @FrayneKonok converting date in phtml?

Comment: What did you try? What error do you get? Please explain more about your problem.

Comment: phtml and html does not fact, its about the PHP. am i right?

Comment: @DocRattie phtml can't read the php syntax so it can't be displayed

Comment: you just have to put this line into html tag.

Comment: where are you running your phtml file ?

Comment: I've just edited it. added the code problem. please check it

Comment: @B.Kevin check my post again

Comment: you want to convert $_POST['sp-to'] or $_GET['sp-to'] to this format dd-mm-yy ?

Comment: @B.Kevin No.., but this value="{$specific_price_to|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}"

Comment: whats in $specific_price_to; maybe `<?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($specific_price_to)); ?>`

Comment: @B.Kevin it is a date value but "Y-m-d"

Answer (score 0):

the `<?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date)); ?>` command is indeed the right way to to it. Maybe you should provide a bit of your code for us to help.

Comment: I've just edited it. added the code problem. please check it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, this might work for what you want to do:

```
<input 
  style="width:160%;" 
  id="sp_to" 
  type="text" 
  class="kb-inpfield 
  datepicker" 
  name="sp_to" 
  validate="isDate" 
  value="<?php date("d-m-Y", strtotime($specific_price_to))?>" 
/>
```

Comment: I want to convert this value="{$specific_price_to|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" not "sp_to"

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $specific_price_to = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($specific_price_to)); ?>
```

to change date format